# Validating Regex: Make sure it will match at least two characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm working on an Android app which will allow users to input regex expressions. I'll use the regex to query a database ([MOTL](http://www.magictraders.com/)), but I don't want to bring down a gigantic list (eg, if a user searches for "." to get every single version of every single MtG card in existence).

The shortest name of any Magic card is "Ow", so I need to allow for a search two characters long (such as, for example, "`^Ow$`"). I want to be able to validate the regex entered into the text field to ensure that it's going to match at *least* two characters once I make my query. For example, searching "`Ac`" is fine, searching "`A`" is not. "`[A-D][e-g]+`" is fine, "`[F-M]*`" is not.

What would be the best way to go about this? I was thinking to iterate through the input, counting +1 for each segment of regex that's guaranteed to match a character (lone characters, character classes, and capture groups, or those followed by `+` or `{n,m}`), and +0 for segments which might not match something (characters, character classes and capture groups followed by `*` or `{0,n}`).

Would that solution work? Is there any better way? Is this a waste of time, since most users will simply type part or all of the name of a card sitting in front of them?

Comment: I think you might want to try to solve the more general problem of "too many results" instead. Find a way to impose a cut-off, or sort and do it by chunks, or just prompt the user and tell them they need to be more specific, etc.

Comment: The issue isn't with displaying many results, it's with ramming the MOTL database for huge queries, and then downloading the results to the mobile device. I only have web access to the MOTL price lists, so I can't simply use a SQL limit or something like that. Each search the user attempts is really two queries, too, since foil and non-foil cards are separate.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off treating the users input as literal but with a "wildcard" character (e.g. `*`) so that they don't have to worry about the details of regular expressions and you don't have to solve this problem directly!

For example, your users could enter "`force of *`" and it would match "Force of Will", "Force of Nature", etc.  This way you can just take their input and replace `\*` with `.*` and use the regex you build instead of worrying about cleaning up their input.

Comment: I like this idea, but if I go this route, I'd still like to allow for regex as an option. The MOTL search will be regex regardless of what I do, so since it's there I'd like to make it available to the users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very naive brute force appraoch, if you are given a regex compare it against all alphanumeric chars (1 by 1) if it matches any then it doesnt meet your minimum length criteria.